# How to set VLookUp with Cells format in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the `FomrulaR1C1` of a cell to equal a vlookup with a variable table array. I have tried to pass the range into the look up with the Cells format. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
For Each myCell In vLookUpRange

            myCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C3, 'Parametrics'!Cells(4,3).Address,Cells(4,4).Address,2,0)"

    Next
```

Can I not use that Cells notation in `FormulaR1C1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use vba notation inside the formula string.  It must be removed from the string and concatenated in using `&`

```
"=VLOOKUP(R[0]C3,'Parametrics'!" & Cells(4,3).Address(1,1,xlR1C1) & ":" & Cells(4,4).Address(1,1,xlR1C1) & ",2,0)"
```

the added `(1,1,xlR1C1)` makes the address absolute and R1C1 style.

You also do not need to loop, just assign the whole at once:

```
vLookUpRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C3,'Parametrics'!" & Cells(4,3).Address(1,1,xlR1C1) & ":" & Cells(4,4).Address(1,1,xlR1C1) & ",2,0)"
```

Comment: If I wanted to pass additional Longs into the cells would it be like:
`"=VLOOKUP(R[0]C3,'Parametrics'!" & Cells( " & Long Value & ",3).Address(1,1,xlR1C1).........`?

Comment: no, once outside the quotes you would use it just like normal,  `"=VLOOKUP(R[0]C3,'Parametrics'!" & Cells(Long Value,3).Address(1,1,xlR1C1).........`